# how to create a custom contact form on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, forms

I would like to create a contact form

How is it better make it with plugin or manual?

I have designed the form on a page. I

Now I would like to validate but I would like to use a plugin as jquery-validator. is it possible?

But when I'll look at the browser. I see it out of box from my web.

Some example. I am a little confused. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this plug in easy to get this https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend either Contact Form 7 or Gravity Forms plugins to customize your contact form on your WordPress site, depending on your budget and use, but both of them are really good.
When it comes to how quickly you can create a standard contact form to your website, Contact Form 7 can be the much better, because the plugin is free to use, as for Gravity Forms, it requires you to purchase the plugin, download the archive file, upload it to your website, and then create a form. Only after this step is complete can you publish it. You can find more detailed info [here](https://themes.artbees.net/blog/custom-contact-form-builders/) about it and **a step by step guide** on how to add them and maximize your use of them. Hope it helps! ;)